Why are $\sigma$-additive Stieltjes contents not left-continuous?
I am working through the book on Measure Theory by Elstrodt and there is something I don't understand about Stieltjes contents.

Theorem 1
Let $\mu: \mathfrak{R} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be a content on the ring $\mathfrak{R}$. Then:
a) $\mu$ is a premeasure
$\iff$ b) For every sequence $(A_n)_{n \geq 1}$ of sets in $\mathfrak{R}$ with $A_n \uparrow A \in \mathfrak{R}$, we have $\mu(A_n) \uparrow \mu(A)$.
$\implies$ c) For every sequence $(A_n)_{n \geq 1}$ of sets in $\mathfrak{R}$ with $A_n \downarrow A$ and $\mu(A_1) < \infty$, we have $\mu(A_n) \downarrow \mu(A)$.
$\iff$ d) For every sequence $(A_n)_{n \geq 1}$ of sets in $\mathfrak{R}$ with $A_n \downarrow \emptyset$ and $\mu(A_1) < \infty$, we have $\mu(A_n) \downarrow 0$.
If $\mu$ is finite, then a)-d) are equivalent.

Now consider the semi-ring $\mathfrak{I} := \{]a,b]: a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a \leq b\}$.

Theorem 2
a) If $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is an increasing function, then $\mu_F: \mathfrak{I} \to \mathbb{R}, \mu_F(]a,b]) := F(b) - F(a) \quad (a \leq b)$ is a finitie content. For two increasing functions $F,G: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $\mu_F = \mu_G$ if and only if $F - G$ is constant.
b) If $\mu: \mathfrak{I} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a finite content, then $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$F(x) := \begin{cases}
        \mu(]0,x]), & \text{for } x \geq 0\\
        -\mu(]x,0]), & \text{for } x < 0
        \end{cases},$$
is increasing and $\mu = \mu_F$.

$\mu_F$ is called the Stieltjes content corresponding to $F$.

Theorem 3
Let $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be increasing and $\mu_F: \mathfrak{I} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the Stieltjes content corresponding to $F$. Then $\mu_F$ is a pre-measure if and only if $F$ is right-continuous.
Proof:
Let $\mu_F$ be a pre-measure and $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Then Theorem 1 implies that for every sequence $b_n \downarrow a$: $F(b_n) - F(a) = \mu_F(]a,b_n]) \to 0 \quad (n \to \infty)$. So $F$ is right-continuous.

I am omitting the proof of the reverse implication for brevity.
Now to my (possibly stupid) question. Why isn't $F$ also left-continuous if $\mu_F$ is a measure? If we consider a sequence $a_n \uparrow b$, then the sets $]a_n,b] \downarrow ]b,b] = \emptyset$ and so $F(b) - F(a_n) = \mu_F(]a_n,b]) \to 0 \quad (n \to \infty)$ or am I missing something completely obvious here?

Take $F=1_{[0,\infty)}$.Then $\mu_F(0,1-{1 \over n}] = 0$ for all $n$ but $\mu_F(0,1] = 1$.

@copper.hat Thanks for your comment. Not sure if I understand your comment correctly, but if $F$ is the indicator function of $[0,\infty)$, then $\mu_F(]0,1-\frac{1}{n}]) = F(1-\frac{1}{n}) - F(0) = 1 - 1 = 0$ and $\mu_F(]0,1]) = F(1) - F(0) = 1 - 1 = 0$ as well?

Yep, the point being that $F$ is not continuous from the left.

@copper.hat I think I still don't get the point. So $F$  is not continuous from the left at $0$ I guess. But is $\mu_F$ a measure? In your example $]0,1−\frac{1}{n}]$ does not converge to $]0,1]$ but rather to $]0,1[$. I also don't understand why the argument used in the proof to show that $F$ is right-continuous does not work to show left-continuity.

I suspect this is what is catching you: Suppose $a_n \to b$, with $a_n < b$ for all $n$. Then $\cap_n (a_n,b] = {b}$ not $\emptyset$.

@copper.hat You're absolutely right. Somehow I failed to notice this. Thanks for clarifying this.

As mentioned by copper.hat in the comments, left-continuity does not necessarily follow for sequences $a_n \to b$ with $a_n < b$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
